# Changes in the list box items by jQuery in ASP.NET is not to do

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two list boxes. One empty and one of five options. 
I've used jQuery to transfer option from the list box. 
And in the end I want to read the second option list box is empty.

The code that I used:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=lbleft.ClientID %>').on('dblclick', 'option', function () {
            var element = $("#lbleft option:selected");
            var value = element.val();
            var text = element.text();
            element.remove();

            $("#<%=lbright.ClientID %>").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>');
        });
        $('#<%=lbright.ClientID %>').on('dblclick', 'option', function () {
            var element = $("#lbright option:selected");
            var value = element.val();
            var text = element.text();
            element.remove();

            $("#<%=lbleft.ClientID %>").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>');
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="auto-style1">
        <form id="Form1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbleft" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbright" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dtload = new DataTable();
        dtload.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
        dtload.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        dtload.Rows.Add("Option1", "1;a;!");
        dtload.Rows.Add("Option2", "2;b;@");
        dtload.Rows.Add("Option3", "3;c;#");
        dtload.Rows.Add("Option4", "4;d;$");
        dtload.Rows.Add("Option5", "5;e;%");

        lbleft.DataSource = dtload;
        lbleft.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int count = 0; count <= Convert.ToInt32(lbright.Items.Count); count++)
    {
        string str = null;
        string[] strArr = null;
        int count2 = 0;
        str = lbright.Items[count].ToString();
        char[] splitchar = { ';' };
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
        for (count2 = 0; count2 <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
        {
            Response.Write(
                "Option" + count + ":<br />" +
                "   " + "Value" + count2 + ":" + strArr[count]
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To me, it is not clear what you are really asking. Improve your question to be more specific.

Comment: What is the issue? Any error message? Please explain properly.

Comment: The problem is that after changing options and press Submit II as its first list box is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have ViewStateMode="Disabled", remove it and the list box will not be empty after submit.

Comment: Both the list box items such as first

Comment: I think I understand what you want. You want to be able upon double click to move the items from the first box to the second box using jquery. After that you want to post the results back to the .net page. In order to do that you can use 2 hidden fields on the page, one for the items in the first listbox and another for the items in the second listbox. In the callback btnSubmit_Click, you need to check the values of the hidden fields.

Comment: Quite true, but the options are many, and we also need to value each option.

Comment: You can append the values with a delimiter like in a json format [[name1:value1], [name2:value2] ...] and insert that in the hidden field.

Comment: For example, to disable anything that would do it.

Comment: You can simply use only asp.net, without jquery and javascript. You will need to set AutoPostBack=true and MouseDoubleClick events on the listboxes. If you want that to happen without page refresh, you can place both of them in UpdatePanel.